# jQuery script only runs once

Tags: jquery, html, google-api

I have this bit of jQuery to control a currency converter via google api. The converter takes an already defined amount, and converts the amount when you select a different currency from the drop down box, however it will only do this once, and you have to refresh to select another currency.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.data').change(function(){
        var cost = $('.itemExtraFieldsValue').html();
        var amount = Number(cost.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));     
        var from = "GBP";
        var to = $('#toCurrency').val();
        var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_converter.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                $('.itemExtraFieldsValue').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How do i make it so you can keep going through various currencies? Thanks!

Edit. Sorry should have put the html up

```
<div id="currencyBox">
    <div class="tractor">
        <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue">£27000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <select name="toCurrency" id="toCurrency">
            <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
            <option value="GBP" selected>United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
            <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
            <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit 2.

Here is the link to my test page, the price given is predefined

http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/currency/

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: added the html, sorry about that!

Comment: Note that you're using the same div to get the input the set the output, so each time you get different value.

Comment: @jcubic i noticed that so have now moved the 'cost' and 'amount' variables to be defined before the .change(function(), thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your link, it can't find element with class `itemExtraFieldsValue` because it is being replaced when first call is made, because of the `replaceWith` you have used.
Try this:

```
function(data){
    $('.itemExtraFieldsValue').html(data);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer, since he get the value from the server once, then the change event bubble to `.data` div, so he don't need to set change event on select.

Answer (score 0):

`.data` is the wrong selector for you selectbox and a `div` doesn't have change event so that wont work.
You should change

```
$('.data').change(function(){
```

to

```
$('.data select').change(function(){
```

or

```
$('#toCurrency').change(function(){
```

in which case you can use

```
var to = $(this).val();
```

as your value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on("change", function(){
    // your stuff here
});
```